# Spotify: get all songs and saved album

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, api, spotify

We are looking to develop a iOS application which would allow users to play songs via Spotify API. And user see all songs and album which save in your music.

Now, how feasible would this be if we were to do this via the API or can we somehow have a single data dump?